# How can we get opens and clicks for an email in the Mailchimp Multivariate or A/B Testing Campaign?

Tags: mailchimp

I tried 2 APIs /sent-to and /email-activity. It look like that Mailchimp don't returns correct results for Multivariate campaign.

I also tried /click-details and /open-details for campaign but did not get any open or click.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks